# Nested if statements and "&&" operator

Tags: c++, if-statement, nested, operator-keyword

```
if(a() && b() && c() && d())
   doSomething();


if(a())
   if(b()) 
      if(c())
         if(d())
            doSomething();
```

Is there "any" performance difference between these two?

For example, in a situation that a() turns 0, will it keep running b(), c() and d() in the first if statement? Or will it work same as the second nested if statement?

Comment: [Short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Comment: It wont call b(), c(), d() if a() evaluates to false. && is a short circuit operator

Comment: @UchiaItachi, it also short-circuits with `if`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy it also short-circuits with `while`.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb, yes -- it read to me like Uchia was trying to make a distinction where none exists.

Comment: All answers need to qualified with 'assuming that there is no relevant overload for `operator&&`'…  But you should never overload that because the semantics of the overloaded operator are not the same as the semantics of the native operator — precisely because there isn't a way to simulate 'short circuit evaluation' in a straight function call.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They're exactly identical.

To test this yourself, run `gcc -S test.c` (presuming that this is where you've put your source) and observe the contents of `test.s`.

---

Here's how the nested-`if` approach compiles in gcc 4.8.1 with default options (annotated with comments):

```
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    A                        # try to call A
    testl   %eax, %eax               # look at its return value
    je  .L3                          # short-circuit if it returned 0
    movl    $0, %eax                 # ...repeat for B, et al.
    call    B
    testl   %eax, %eax
    je  .L3
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    C
    testl   %eax, %eax
    je  .L3
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    D
    testl   %eax, %eax
    je  .L3
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    doSomething
.L3:
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

Here's how the `&&` approach compiles:

```
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    A                           # try to call A
    testl   %eax, %eax                  # look at its return value
    je  .L3                             # short-circuit if it returned 0
    movl    $0, %eax                    # ...repeat for B, et al.
    call    B
    testl   %eax, %eax
    je  .L3
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    C
    testl   %eax, %eax
    je  .L3
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    D
    testl   %eax, %eax
    je  .L3
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    doSomething
.L3:
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```