# Should if(a&&b) take more time than if(a) if(b)?

Tags: java, c#, native

I used the following simple logic to answer a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25473040/nested-if-statements-and-operator) like this one:

```
1:   if(a)        // 1 operation
2:   if (b)       // 1 operation
```

and

```
1:  if(a && b) // 1, 1(&&), 1 => 3 operations.
```

So, 2 operations  versus 3, but in the first example the compiler needs to call another instruction to be executed.

Is this logic true?. 
Does it depend on the compiler?.
Does calling an empty instruction like only `;` cost the compiler some noticable time?.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25473040/nested-if-statements-and-operator)  also discuss the same problem but not considering this logic. 
Please help us to clarify this issue.

Comment: i don't think they are different and performance will depend on usage. if you use first type before second type then first type will take more time and reverse is also true. basically both are same.

Comment: In case of && operator if a is passed then b will not be evaluated at all. Its short circuit.

Comment: Wait... just to check. Are we talking about runtime speed or compilation speed? You've used phrases like "*Does calling an empty instruction... cost **the compiler** some noticable time*", yet I can't help thinking you're talking about runtime.

Comment: @TiyebBellal Why does compilation speed matter? Any difference in compilation will be minute and only occurs once.

Comment: @muasif80 if its not checking b that will be || and not &&

Comment: @Friendy Oh yes you are right. I had to say that if condition 'a' is failed then condition 'b' will not be evaluated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two methods to answer such a question *precisely*:

1.) Look at the IL code (and/or) aassembly code produce and count the CPU cycles needed to execute this code (Hint: this is not for beginners)

2.) Build a small test programm which executes both variants a large number of time, use StopWatch() to create a uesful and readable timing output, run it several times.

3.) Speculate about what you think the optimization step of the compiler is able to do and what this software will do, argue with others for hours

Comment: I'm not sure it counts as an answer if you merely explain how to obtain the answer. This is interesting information, nonetheless.

Comment: @Duncan give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime

Answer (score 2):

I assumed the compiler would produce the same byte code for your two cases. So I tested this with two different source files:

```
public class Test1 {    
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args[0].equals("a"))
      if (args[1].equals("b"))
        System.out.println("Foo");
  }    
}
```

and...

```
public class Test2 {    
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args[0].equals("a") && args[1].equals("b"))
      System.out.println("Foo");
  }    
}
```

Inspecting their byte code with `javap -c Test1` etc., the results are identical:

```
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: iconst_0
       2: aaload
       3: ldc           #2                  // String a
       5: invokevirtual #3                  // Method java/lang/String.equals:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
       8: ifeq          30
      11: aload_0
      12: iconst_1
      13: aaload
      14: ldc           #4                  // String b
      16: invokevirtual #3                  // Method java/lang/String.equals:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
      19: ifeq          30
      22: getstatic     #5                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      25: ldc           #6                  // String Foo
      27: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      30: return
```

Consequently, the performance would be identical. Although I welcome comments if anyone can think of an example where different byte code is produced.

My results are using Oracle's `javac` from Java 1.7. Results could be different with other compilers, although I suspect they won't be for this case.

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 approaches to think about your question:

1. *the Java language definition*

   - language defines that the 2nd example will use short-circuit execution which means **in the case the `if` statements will contain any code, the 2nd example may execute faster**
2. *the JVM optimization*

   - **the JVM runtime will remove the dead code blocks if it can proof they don't have any side-effects**

Comment: Your first argument doesn't make sense to me. In the first example, the short-circuit execution is implied from the structure of the code. And your second argument doesn't make much sense unless you can explain what dead code blocks you think we have here?