# Is there difference in processing time between multiple if statement and one if with multiple condition?

Tags: time

I prefer to avoid nested if but I wonder if there's time difference between these two :

```
if(a && b)
{
    ...
}
```

**or**

```
if(a)
{
    if(b)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29033373/should-ifab-take-more-time-than-ifa-ifb

Comment: one more
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25473040/nested-if-statements-and-operator?lq=1

Comment: It depends on the language you are using. It is very possible to imagine a programming language where the two examples perform differently (and very possible to imagine the opposite too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the same.

After `a` gives `true` in `(a && b && c && ...)`, `b` is tested, then `c` and so on – one by one until some expression in chain will result `false`. After it happens all subsequent expressions will be skipped. As far as I know it works the same way in all C-like languages.

Your code will be more readable if you use `&&` operator instead of nesting many `if` blocks.

Answer (score 1):

They're exactly identical.

However it depends on your compiler , you have not mentioned the language you will be using.

But most of the compiler will interpret these both code into same thing

example for java
[Should if(a&&b) take more time than if(a) if(b)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29033373/should-ifab-take-more-time-than-ifa-ifb)

example for c++
[Nested if statements and "&&" operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25473040/nested-if-statements-and-operator?lq=1)